# Apache mod_rewrite: unknown browser redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have .htaccess file:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^enter(.*)$ /admin$1 [L]`
I want to make internal server redirect to **/admin/some/info** page when user try to use **/enter/some/info/** url.
And this is works correct except in the case **/enter** url. In this case server response is 301 and browser redirect to page **/admin**
Please, help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the redirect to happen only when there is something after the "enter", the  try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^enter/(.+)$ /admin/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer! :)
I've just solved redirect problem the same way:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^enter/?(.*)$ /admin$1`

Comment: Be careful, this regular expression is a bit different, it will still send example.com/enter to example.com/admin.